# Is it possible to have a pivot table automatically incorporate newly added 'Filter by' values or show the current values?

Tags: google-sheets

I've made a test sheet here (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17l49Rn3ZbNx-upzBtmRtsJBHQiCKXuYPs8SMTyrcw9k/edit#gid=0)

You'll notice that the pivot table IS correctly pulling in ALL the data in A:B, not just limited to the existing rows of data.

This way, as new rows are appended, the data is automatically added to the pivot.

However, I've discovered a limitation. If a new row contains a new Name value, e.g., C, then that will NOT get automatically added to the pivot, since the pivot has a filter. Even though the filter is for "All items", since C wasn't existing at the time at which the filter was added, once I add a row C, I have to manually adjust the filter (re-select all) to pull it into the pivot.

This is not desired behavior for me, I would like the pivot to not be constrained (i.e., if it previously was set to select all, then continue selecting all) UNLESS I had said only A, then don't give me C even if C is appended!

Is this possible?

Or if not, at the very least, is it possible to print out the filter somewhere formulaically? (in a cell, `=Filter(pivot)`), this way at least I have a warning/reminder?

Other solutions to deal with this welcome!

Comment: I don't know if this can be solved in pivot tables.  [My answer below](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/173051) simply offers an alternative that dynamically updates.  Pending a pivot table-based solution I think that's better than implementing a warning/reminder.

Comment: Ah so... unfortunately the pivot table in actuality is quite complex, and I really need to use it. HOWEVER I do think the Filter can be a good way of highlighting missing names!

Answer (score 0):

## Alternative Using QUERY

For what you are doing you could use QUERY Function instead which would update dynamically. I also included at the end a typical formula that returns items from one list that are not found in another.

### Grand Total at Bottom

You could add conditional formatting (font and fill, but not borders) if you want to make the **Grand Total** stand out.

```
={ QUERY(A:B, "Select A, SUM(B) Where A is not Null
     Group by A Label SUM(B) 'SUM of Amount'",1);
   "Grand Total", SUM(B:B) }
```

[image: Example showing source data, results and formula]

### Grand Total at Top

You can also move the **Grand Total** to the top.  This might be useful for long lists and also allows directly applying formatting including borders.

```
={ "Name", "Total Amount"; "Grand Total", SUM(B:B);
   QUERY(A:B, "Select A, SUM(B) Where A is not Null
     Group by A Label A '', SUM(B) ''",1) }
```

[image: Example showing source data, results and formula]

### Find Missing Names

Searches **Name** column A for any values that do not also appear in pivot table **Name** column E and returns any matches as an array of values.

```
=FILTER(A:A, NOT(COUNTIF(E:E, A:A)))
```

[image: Image Description]